# Problems with django types

Tags: python, django

When i want to save this django file:

```
from django.urls import path
import django.views  

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view')
```

I get an error :

"Name 'views' is not defined"

If i change "import django.views" for "from . import views" I get an error:

"Attempted relative import with no known parent package"

I have **init**.py file with command "import django.views". If I change this command for "import views" I get an error:

"Unable to import "views""

File "views":

Содержимое файла views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h4>Hello</h4>")
```

Structure of the project:

```
|__Django
 |__firstsite
  |__firstsite
   |__ __pycache__
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ asgi.py
   |__ settings.py
   |__ urls.py
   |__ wsgi.py
  |__main
   |__ __pycache__
   |__ migrations
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ admin.py
   |__ apps.py
   |__ models.py
   |__ tests.py
   |__ urls.py
   |__ views.py
  |__db.sqlite3
  |__manage.py
```

What should I do with it?

Comment: Did you create an app named `django`? Because by doing that you "override" the django module of the `Django` package.

Comment: Try it.

`from . import views`

Comment: I wrote about      "from . import views"   .